# Share config custom.xml for specific site in Alfresco

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I don't want few aspects to be visible in manage aspect for a particular site. So I changed share config custom XML. But this change is being reflected for all sites. How can I make this specific for a site?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 3):

You should use the concept of seperate share modules per site, using a site evaluator:

create a share-extension-mysitename-module.xml file in alfresco\site-data\extensions\ that looks like so:

```
        <id>My site module</id>
        <auto-deploy>true</auto-deploy>
        <evaluator type="site.module.evaluator">
            <params>
                <sites>mysitename</sites>
                <applyForNonSites>false</applyForNonSites>
            </params>
        </evaluator>
        <customizations>
            <customization>
                <targetPackageRoot>org.alfresco</targetPackageRoot>
                <sourcePackageRoot>com.mypackage</sourcePackageRoot>
            </customization>
        </customizations>
        <configurations>
            <config evaluator="string-compare" condition="DocumentLibrary" >
            ...
               <aspects>
                    <visible>
                        <aspect name="my:visibleaspect" />
                    </visible>
                </aspects>
            </config>
        </configurations>           

    </module>
</modules>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, I don't think this is possible to have a custom share-config by site.

I see two (probably unsatisfying) solutions :

1. You can create your [custom evaluator](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/concepts/dev-extensions-share-evaluators.html) and use it to make some parts accessibles (or not).

   ```
   <bean id="evaluator.doclib.action.siteBased" class="xx.xx.xx.web.evaluator.SiteBasedEvaluator">
      <property name="sites">
          <list>
              <value>mysite</value>
          </list>
      </property>
   </bean>

   public class SiteBasedEvaluator extends BaseEvaluator {

      private List<String> sites;

      public SiteBasedEvaluator() {
          super();
      }

      public SiteBasedEvaluator(String... pSites) {
          super();
          sites = Arrays.asList(pSites);
      }

     public boolean evaluate(JSONObject jsonObject) {
          Boolean isFound = false;
          if (sites != null) {
              for (String site : sites) {
                  isFound = site.equals(getSiteId(jsonObject));
                  if (isFound) {
                      break;
                 }
              }
          }
         return isFound;
   }
   ```
2. You can deploy two share war in your tomcat, each one having the share-config-custom.xml you want